# Angular Bootstrap datepicker popup issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-bootstrap

I have problem regarding angular bootstrap datepicker popup.
When i click on icon to open datepicker popup it will append html to element but popup is not coming.

I have checked up everything but i'm stuck here i dont have any idea regarding it.
Anybody can help me??

I'm using angular bootstrap v `Version: 0.12.1 - 2015-02-20`

I have used this code :

```
<div class="input-group w-md">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-click="open($event)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </div>
```

Check console : 
[image]

Javascript controllers :

```
$scope.today = function() {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.dt = null;
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
        return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
    };

    $scope.toggleMin = function() {
        $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();

    $scope.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.opened = !$scope.opened;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.format = 'dd.MM.yyyy';
```

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript code working with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jPPS0tweOQxcgseFjpuI?p=preview):

i copy your code to my plunker, use `open1()` instead of `open($event)`

Comment: Hello, you are using *uib-datepicker-popup* but its latest angular bootstrap i'm using older version

Comment: where is your plunker?

Comment: i think you can use ui-bootstrap, i have updated the plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/YKhM4bt1bNLu4b8Org73?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114608/discussion-between-vino-dang-and-jivani-jaydeep).